# Ledger Nano S wont connect to Ledger Live App on Linux

Tags: ledger-nano-s

`Ledger Nano S` wont connect to `Ledger Live App` using latest version `2.54.0`.
I do that on my linux machine with ubuntu 18.04.

I tried every fix they offered?
after running Ledger live in my terminal I get the following error.

```
[7815:0307/134336.019574:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find 
SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, 
format: RED_8, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke with Ledger live support and they told me that they do not support ubuntu 18.04 anymore.